# Getting error "com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch_extension" could not be found in the registry" while doing build via JENKINS

Tags: java, jenkins, websphere, build-process

I am triggering build for my Java Application via JENKINS but getting following error:

```
Error executing deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException. Error is Application "com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch_extension" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, com.ibm.etools.rdbschemagen.bvt, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.CodeGen, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.JMerger, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, com.ibm.etools.sqlparse.SQLParserTest, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator, com.ibm.ws.rapiddeploy.core.WRDExec, org.eclipse.emf.importer.java.Java2GenModel, com.ibm.etools.sqlmodel.bvt..

[exec] java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch_extension" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, com.ibm.etools.rdbschemagen.bvt, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.CodeGen, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.JMerger, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, com.ibm.etools.sqlparse.SQLParserTest, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator, com.ibm.ws.rapiddeploy.core.WRDExec, org.eclipse.emf.importer.java.Java2GenModel, com.ibm.etools.sqlmodel.bvt.

[exec]  at <unknown class>.<unknown method>(Unknown Source)
[exec]  at <unknown class>.<unknown method>(Unknown Source)
[exec]  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
[exec]  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
[exec]  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
[exec]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[exec]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[exec]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[exec]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BootLoaderLoader.run(BootLoaderLoader.java:494)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BatchDeploy.execute(BatchDeploy.java:114)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.execute(EJBDeploy.java:107)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.deploy(EJBDeploy.java:348)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.main(EJBDeploy.java:310)
```

Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically caused by a corrupted/out of date config cache in the deploytool directory. Try to delete everything **but** the config.ini file from WAS/deploytool/itp/configuration (of course, don't delete -- move to a safe place first and if the ejbdeploy then works, **then** delete).

Can also be caused by a wrong contents of config.ini or a corrupt FP install, but the above is the most common issue I see.